# How to reset a wizard sapui5

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I have a wizard that I finish and I want to reset after that and go back to the first step with all other steps invalidated just like it was at first.
I can reset the model of my data but I always end up in the last step of wizard

Comment: The only time I used a wizard I ended up destroying it and reloading the fragment it was in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the following code in a function that gets called every time you enter the wizard (not `onInit`, this gets called only once, better would be your `onRouteMatched` method).

```
var oWizard = this.byId("myWizard");
var oFirstStep = oWizard.getSteps()[0];
oWizard.discardProgress(oFirstStep);
// scroll to top
oWizard.goToStep(oFirstStep);
// invalidate first step
oFirstStep.setValidated(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are missing the following line to reset progress:

```
oWizard.discardProgress(
    oWizard.getSteps()[0]
);
```

> Discards all progress done from the given step(incl.) to the end of the wizard.

See [here](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.Wizard/methods/discardProgress) for the API documentation of the discard function.
The function needs the first wizardStep as a parameter.